# Scrolling text isn't shown fully inside textBlock WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, text, scroll

So I'm pretty new to WPF and its XAML design elements. What I want to achieve is to have scrolling text, with infinite repeat. Note that I'm getting text from an online resource and it can be pretty long. The problem is, text is shown just enough to fit the element, in my case Width="1080". What do I need to modify in XAML or code in order to achieve this effect? Here is my code and XAML.

```
<Border x:Name="FooterBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="67" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="1080" Background="#FFDE3E3E" Margin="0">
       <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" FontSize="22" Name="txtScrolling" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1080">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                 <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                 <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                      <BeginStoryboard>
                          <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                               <DoubleAnimation
                                        From="1080" To="-1080"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="translate"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                        Duration="0:0:15" />
                           </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                 </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
            <Label x:Name="BottomScrollingText" Content="Custom text for scrolling test, this is just an example of how big text can't with within a certain width" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0"/>
       </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

And here is the code that's getting the text from an online resource

```
public void InitScrollingText()
{
     WebClient client = new WebClient();
     Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://touch.hola.rs/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sample-scrolling-text.txt");
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
     String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
     BottomScrollingText.Content = content;
}
```

Here is the link to the image, since I can't post images without enough rep.
https://prnt.sc/q02ted

As you can see, the red text area is full, but the text is much longer, so it doesn't scroll fully, some parts of the text are cut out in order to fit the width of the element.

Comment: Could you please claridy your issue? What do you expect to see in the `Border`exactly?

Comment: Are you basically wanting your `BottomScrollingText` to act as a marquee?

Comment: @Tronald Yes, I'm trying to achieve marquee effect, but the part of my text is being cut out.

Answer (score 0):

Update, as I have found out on other similar question, the problem was using XAML elements that didn't allow content to be seen if it exceeds their parent ActualWidth. Here is the XAML that works correctly for this problem.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stack" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <local:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter" />
                    <Storyboard x:Key="slide">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}" 
                                 To="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter}, ElementName=TextToScroll}" 
                                 Duration="00:00:30"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny2"
                                 RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <Label Content="something" x:Name="TextToScroll" Canvas.Left="0" Foreground="#E9D460" Padding="0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36">
                    <Label.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.SizeChanged">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Label.Triggers>
                    <Label.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny2" X="0"/>
                    </Label.RenderTransform>
                </Label>
            </StackPanel>
```

EDIT: Here is the code for NegatingConverter

```
public class NegatingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return -((double)value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return +(double)value;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```